# How do you detect when HTML5 audio has finished playing (more than once)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am having a problem detecting when an  tag is finished playing an mp3. When I do something like this:

```
     myAudio.addEventListener("ended", function() 
     {
          alert("ended");
     });
```

It only occurs the first time the audio is played. When I play the audio again, nothing happens. The same thing happens when I use the `onended=doThis();` method. I've heard maybe there is a way to do it in jQuery, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've also heard there might be a way to fix it by changing the audio div `id` every time the mp3 is played, but this doesn't work for me because I need the `id` to stay the same.

Did anyone get any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MvzFN/2/ (see/listen in chrome): in this fiddle oneneded event seems to be always triggered

Comment: Try creating the audio tag in html and not in javascript. Does it work for you still?

Comment: yes it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/MvzFN/3/

Comment: @AndersonGreen this is not a duplicate, the other answer shows up the method the OP is already using and asking for help on a specific behavior

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `ended` event is created based on `.currentTime` attribute.
http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-ended

So, all you have to do is set the `.currentTime` to zero again.

```
myAudio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
     myAudio.currentTime = 0;
     console.log("ended");
});
```

Comment: That did it! But I also had to pause it before that because otherwise it would just be an endless loop

Comment: I tried this but for me it didn't work. though i found re-adding the event listener before each play did the trick for me.  I'm using the Tizen Web so api so not sure if that's what's causing it to be different for me or not. but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: one other thing i found out when using Tizen. using this method will not guarantee that the effects of the function will happen after the media has ended, they will happen just not always after the media has actually ended. it's better to put the  onended into the html tag as that has that was the only way I could get it to work as expected.