# JavaScript function refuses to execute in order

Tags: javascript

One of the case statements in the top function below is not going in order. Currently, it goes straight to the prompt, and if you click Cancel, `operatorPickup` is never heard at all. If I type 'police', I get the police recording which is in *a different function called at the **end** of the current function* and *then* I get `OperatorAnswer` which makes absolutely no sense which it is going in the order 2, 3, 1 - when 3 is not even in the same function!

From previous experience, I tried delaying the prompt in case alerts, prompts, or confirms blocked the UI and took precedence, but that didn't help either.

```
function response() {
        switch(number) {
            case "0":
                var operatorPickup = new Audio('OperatorAnswer.wav');
                operatorPickup.play();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    number = prompt("Operator, your number please? (Numbers only; enter 'police' for police and emergency)");
                    number = number;
                    operatorPutCallThrough();
                }, 9);
                break;
            case "911":
                var pickup911 = new Audio('911-xxx-fleet.mp3');
                pickup911.play();
                break;
            case "18477651008":
                var pickupMCI = new Audio('MCI.wav');
                pickupMCI.play();
                break;
            case "8675309":
                var pickup8675309 = new Audio('discoornis-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickup8675309.play();
                break;
            case "police":
                break;
            default:
                var pickupDefault = new Audio('ldcircuits-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickupDefault.play();
        }
    }
    function operatorPutCallThrough() {
        if (number == "police") {
            var operatorPoliceTransfer = new Audio('OperatorPolice.wav');
            operatorPoliceTransfer.play();
        }
        response();
    }
```

How can I force case "0" in `switch(number)` to execute **in order**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an event listener on the `play()` so it will only prompt once media file finished playing.

I've never worked with HTML5's `audio` as of yet but this question: [Detecting when HTML5 audio is finished playing (more than once)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103582/detecting-when-html5-audio-is-finished-playing-more-than-once) suggested how you can listen to the event so you can try:

```
operatorPickup.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    number = prompt("Operator, your number please? (Numbers only; enter 'police' for police and emergency)");
    number = number;
    operatorPutCallThrough();
});
```

**BEFORE** the `operatorPickup.play();`

Comment: If I do this, no recording plays at all, but the alert box doesn't pop up. Everything just stops

Comment: that doesn't make sense... do you have any errors in the console? did you add the eventlistener between `var operatorPickup = new Audio('OperatorAnswer.wav');` and `operatorPickup.play();` ?

Comment: I had it before the var operatorPickup define too, that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

If you click cancel, the variable `number` gets set to `null`, which isn't in the case statements. If you want to go to the same case on null and 0, you should add `case null` immediately above or below `case "0"`. If there isn't a `break` before the next case, the switch-statement will execute the next case and so on, so you can stack case statements without breaks over the code that should execute for any one of those cases.

Comment: Hmm... I tried setting var previousNumber = number and then after case 0 runs changing number to previousNumber if number is null... but consoleLog is reporting nothing for any of them...