# Why won't my button play my sound and go to the link?

Tags: javascript, html

This looks like a basic problem but failed to find the answer.. Is there anything I need to add for the button to bring a user to the home page and play the sound? At the moment it only plays the sound. I want it to play the sound immediately then go to the homepage.

```js
function playBeep() {
  var sound = document.getElementById("Sound")
  sound.play()
}
```

```html
<div class="animatedButton">

  <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>

  <a href="Home.html"> </a>
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Where do you tell the browser to navigate to a new page? And if you change the page immediately, the user won't hear the sound.

Comment: I have created the button that the user clicks to go to the home button, the animatedButton is the button that is supposed to play the sound and then link .

Comment: Because there is no connection between the button and the `<a>` element. To do this you would need to set location.href when the audio completes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103582/detecting-when-html5-audio-is-finished-playing-more-than-once)) - but custom audio like that can be quite annoying.  Also do not direct link to soundjay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until the `<audio>` element is done playing, then tell the browser to navigate to a new page:

```js
function playBeep() {
  var sound = document.getElementById("Sound");
  sound.play();
  sound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    location.href = 'Home.html';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="animatedButton">

  <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the most simplest and effective answer, also helps me remove the a tag which you aren't supposed to wrap around a button for some reason. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

just need to add your link  `window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";`

```js
function playBeep() {
  var sound = document.getElementById("Sound")
  sound.play();
  window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<div class="animatedButton">

  <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>

  <a href="Home.html"> </a>
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function playBeep() {
  var sound = document.getElementById("Sound")
  sound.play();
  window.location.href = '/'; //Go to HomePage

}
```

```html
<div class="animatedButton">

  <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>

  <a href="Home.html"> </a>
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="Home.html"> </a>`

Your button is not in the `<a>`tag
Maybe this will work :

```
<a href="Home.html"> 
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the closing tag of a.
the tag "a" has to wrap the whole button.

```
<a href="Home.html">
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
    <img src="img/Home.png">
  </button>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `jQuery` to listen for the sound to end and redirect the user.

```js
/* Bind Ended Event to Sound */
$('#Sound').on('ended', function(){
    console.log('User Redirected');
});

/* Bind Click Event to Button */
$('#aButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#Sound')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animatedButton">
    <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>
    <a href="Home.html"></a>
    <button id="aButton">
        <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/home.png">
    </button>
</div>
```

Or you could use just `JavaScript` to listen for the sound to end and redirect the user.

```js
/* Variable Defaults */
var sound = document.getElementById('Sound');
var button = document.getElementById('aButton');

/* Bind Ended Event to Sound */
sound.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    console.log('User Redirected');
});

/* Bind Click Event to Button */
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sound.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animatedButton">
    <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>
    <a href="Home.html"></a>
    <button id="aButton">
        <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/home.png">
    </button>
</div>
```